# Characters in aside not printing correctly

Tags: text, rendering, friggeri-cv

I am having this strange issue where characters aren't being printed correctly.

My code uses an aside like so:

```latex
\begin{aside}
\href{mailto:name@email.com}{
\textbf{name}\\
email.com
}
\href{mailto:name2@email2.com}{
\textbf{name2}\\
email2.com
}
\end{aside}
```

Here is the full version: https://gist.github.com/o4dev/8469dda5a4cc361025bb64a7882e44fd

I am unsure but believe the aside environment is from frixggeri-cv document type.

However, this is resulting in:

[image: demo]
Any Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't know which package/class defines the `aside` environment. Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) out of your code snippet so that we can compile and see what the problem is?

Comment: If you are using the [tag:friggeri-cv] template, you may want to include the tag.

Comment: I have added the code. It is straight from a friggeri-cv template. When I try to add that tag though I am told I do not have enough reputation.